# Keep values of boolean HTML attributes when using lxml html.tostring

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I have the following HTML code:

```
<iframe src="https://src.com/link" width="300" height="300" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize"></iframe>
```

Is there any way, using lxml in python, to preserve the values of boolean attributes? In my example the `noresize` attribute? Here is the output, that lxml produces when parsed with `html.fragments_fromstring` method and then serialized back to html with `html.tostring`:

```
<iframe src="https://src.com/link" width="300" height="300" scrolling="no" noresize></iframe>
```

I can see that after the initial parsing, the value of the `noresize` attribute is present in the element's attribute dictionary:

```
{'src': 'https://src.com/link', 'width': '300', 'height': '300', 'scrolling': 'no', 'noresize': 'noresize'}
```

But when serializing back using `html.tostring`, the value is discarded. I know that removing the value is completly valid in HTML and the value itself has no real effect, but I would like to preserve the original value.

Here is the complete code:

```
from lxml import html
html_frag = "<iframe src=\"https://src.com/link\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" scrolling=\"no\" noresize=\"noresize\"></iframe>"
html_tree = html.fragments_fromstring(html_frag, parser=html.HTMLParser())
html_str = ""
for element in html_tree:
    print(element.attrib)
    html_str += html.tostring(element, encoding=str)

print(html_str)
```

Result:

```
{'src': 'https://src.com/link', 'width': '300', 'height': '300', 'scrolling': 'no', 'noresize': 'noresize'}
<iframe src="https://src.com/link" width="300" height="300" scrolling="no" noresize></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens (it may have to do something with the fact that [Inline frames may not be resized (and thus, they do not take the noresize attribute)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html)), but try this and see if it works for you:

```
html_frag = """<iframe src="https://src.com/link" width="300" height="300" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize"></iframe>"""
html_tree = html.fragments_fromstring(html_frag, parser=html.HTMLParser())

for element in html_tree:            
    targets = element.xpath('//iframe')        
    for target in targets:
        print(etree.tostring(target))
```

Output:

```
<iframe src="https://src.com/link" width="300" height="300" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize"/>
```

Comment: because `eetree.tostring` serializes the tree as a XML, where boolean attributes are not allowed ( as opposed to `html.tostring` which serializes it as a HTML).